# rename only one column during Select

Tags: postgresql

I would like to rename  the `time_2` field to `time` when I do a select.

I see examples using `[original_column] as [new_column]`.  But I want to keep all the other columns to remain the same so `*` is needed.

```
select * 
from (select * 
      FROM players 
      where symbol=$1 and time_2 <= $2 
      ORDER BY time_2 desc 
      limit $3) temp 
ORDER BY time_2 asc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't the way you want it , the only way is to add as duplicate column and give it alias:

```
select * , time_2 as time
from (select * 
      FROM players 
      where symbol=$1 and time_2 <= $2 
      ORDER BY time_2 desc 
      limit $3) temp 
ORDER BY time_2 asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for that – you have to explicitly write all columns in the `SELECT` list.